# Excel how to extract all sheets and save them as single files in .xls 2003 version

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Excel 2010 and the file is xlsx, but I want to extract all the sheets of my workbook as single files in xls 2003 version. At the end I would get 10 files as my 10 sheets.

I don't have any idea how to perform this task.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT** this is the code I was trying to adapt

```
Sub SaveSheets()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy
        'Use this line if you want to break any links:
        BreakLinks Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Close True, strPath & ws.Name & ".xls"
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I'll update with the code I was trying to use

Comment: 1+ Thank you Pnuts I solved with your link, very kind.